# How to find record by its datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord

The structure of Event table:

```
Event(id: integer, user_id: integer, event_type: string, 
  external_timestamp: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Contents of the table:

```
[#<Event id: 1, mailing_user_id: 1, event_type: "Open", 
 external_timestamp: "2013-10-05 09:49:11", 
 created_at: "2013-06-12 08:54:24", updated_at: "2013-06-12 08:54:24">]
```

I'm trying to find object by its datetime

```
dt = DateTime.parse("2013-10-05 09:49:11")
Event.where(:external_timestamp => dt)
```

But this construction returns empty result.

Maybe it's because of date format?

```
Event.first.external_timestamp #=> Sat, 05 Oct 2013 09:49:11 UTC +00:00
```

How to write condition to find the object by its datetime? Thanks

Comment: That will work. You probably don't have a record with an `external_timestamp` of that value.

Comment: I've updated the question, the problem that it has that date but doesn't return it.

Comment: There is no reason why that wouldn't work, and it works fine for me. Check that `dt` is the correct parsed date and check `Event.find(1).external_timestamp`.

Comment: maybe it's because of date format, please look at the content of timestamp

Comment: What database are you using? I checked this with SQLite and it stores dates as follows: `2013-05-28 23:40:09.342739`, but Rails ignores the `.342739` and that's why it can't find the record. Not sure if this problem exists for other databases as well. When I try `Model.where(:date_field => '2013-05-28 23:40:09.342739')` it does work.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.1.62-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Did you check the record in the database? Does it have milliseconds?

Comment: How to get this straight date? I used 'select external_timestamp from events;' and it gives me just text data.

Comment: Apparently MySQL doesn't store milliseconds. Then the problem could be  the timezone. Does it work if you use this for your query: `dt = Time.zone.parse('2013-10-05 09:49:11')` instead of `DateTime.parse`?

Comment: The problem because of time zone

Comment: @Mischa, you're right, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with time zone, thanks to [Mischa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84631/mischa), here's how I resolved it:

```
t = Time.zone.parse("2013-10-05 09:49:11")
Event.where(:external_timestamp => t) # successfully finds the record
```